# Showing $\tan x = \frac{\sin\alpha\sin y}{1 - \sin\alpha\cos y}$, given $\sin x = \sin \alpha\sin (x + y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I've been struggling with this for some time but can't prove what question asks.

Question is as follows:

> If $\sin x = \sin \alpha\sin (x + y)$, prove that
> $$\tan x = \frac{\sin\alpha\sin y}{1 - \sin\alpha\cos y}$$

I began by expanding what is given, i.e.
$$\sin x = \sin \alpha(\sin x\cos y + \cos x\sin y)$$

expanding gives:

$$\sin x = \sin \alpha\sin x\cos y + \sin\alpha\cos x\sin y$$

Now my first question is regarding this equality. Does this show $\sin\alpha\cos y = 1$ and $\cos x \sin y =0$?

Whether or not this is true, I have been unable to manipulate what is given into what is required. A brief outline of my method is as follows:

If

$$\sin x = \sin \alpha\sin (x + y)$$

then

$$\tan x = \frac{\sin \alpha\sin (x + y)}{\cos x}$$

i.e.

$$\tan x = \frac{\sin \alpha(\sin x\cos y + \cos x\sin y)}{\cos x}$$

giving

$$\tan x = \sin \alpha(\tan x\cos y + \sin y)$$

Despite many attempts from different angles of attack, but similar to that shown, I have been unable to complete the proof.

I should also add that earlier in the chapter, the author, C G Nobbs, gave the following two identities:

$$\sec x\sec y\sin (x + y) = \tan x + \tan y$$
$$\sec x\sec y\cos (x + y) = 1 - \tan x\tan y$$

Not sure if these are of any help but thought I should include them for the sake of completeness.

Many thanks in advance for any hints given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right in the middle part--you're almost there!

Right after where you say "giving...", just before "Despite many attempts...", multiply out the right side, collect all the terms with $\tan x$ on one side, and factor $\tan x$ out. This will give you what you want.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply; I understand the proof now and cannot see why it eluded me for so long - hindsight is a wonderful thing. Is it possible to tell me briefly what is wrong with my initial question regarding what was given in the question. I've tried to do something along the lines of equating coefficients but tot sure what is wrong with my logic there.

Answer (score 2):

Divide $$\sin x = \sin \alpha\sin x\cos y + \sin\alpha\cos x\sin y$$ by $\cos x$ to get $$\tan x = \sin \alpha\tan x\cos y + \sin\alpha\sin y$$ and solve for $\tan x$

Answer (score 1):

To derive the expression $\tan x = \frac{\sin\alpha\sin y}{1 - \sin\alpha\cos y}$ from the given equation $\sin x = \sin \alpha\sin (x + y)$, we can use trigonometric identities. We have:

$$\sin x = \sin \alpha\sin (x + y)$$

Using the sum-to-product identity for sine, we get:
$$ \sin x = \sin \alpha (\sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y) $$

Isolated $\sin x$:
$$ \sin x - \sin \alpha \sin x \cos y = \sin \alpha \cos x \sin y $$
$$\sin x (1 - \sin \alpha \cos y) = \sin \alpha \cos x \sin y $$

Finally, solve for $\sin x$:
$$\sin x = \frac{\sin \alpha \cos x \sin y}{1 - \sin \alpha \cos y} $$

Now, since $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, we have:
$$\tan x = \frac{\sin \alpha \sin y}{1 - \sin \alpha \cos y} $$